# Removing list item in to-do list using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let me start by saying that:

1. I've already looked at a lot of documentation about resolving this
   problem
2. I'm still very new to JavaScript.

The problem: the remove button doesn't remove the corresponding content, which is a `li` item. To me, that means the problem is in step 7 `removeToDo.addEventListener` or in step 8 `function removeToDoItem`, but I could be wrong.

```js
//2) SECOND STEP: build the function that will control everything
function onReady() {

  //2.1) creates and houses the current state of to-do list
  var toDos = [];

  //3) THIRD STEP: Event Listener - this accesses the HTML form element
  var addToDoForm = document.getElementById('addToDoForm');

  //2.2) build function that creates/adds list items
  function createNewToDo() {

    //2.3) accesses the text input from the form
    var newToDoText = document.getElementById('newToDoText');

    //2.4) adds new item to the toDos array
    toDos.push({
      title: newToDoText.value,
      complete: false
    });

    //2.5) clears the text in the form input field so user doesn't need to
    newToDoText.value='';

    renderTheUI(toDos);
  }

  //8) EIGHT STEP: build function that deletes list item
  function removeToDoItem() {
    newLi.toDoList.removeChild(newLi);
    renderTheUI(toDos);
  }

  //5) FIFTH STEP: build the function that will render the UI
  function renderTheUI(toDos) {

    //5.1) Accesses the <ul> in the HTML
    var toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoList');

    //5.9 sets each newLi to an empty string
    toDoList.innerHTML = '';

    //5.2) Use forEach() array method to render each to-do as an <li> in the <ul>
    toDos.forEach(function(toDo) {

      //5.3 creates new <li>
      var newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.setAttribute('id', 'myLi');

      //5.4 creates new checkbox
      var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

      //6) SIXTH STEP: create remove button and set its attributes
      var removeToDo = document.createElement('input');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('value', 'remove');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('id', 'removeButton');

      //5.5 set var checkbox as a type checkbox
      checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

      //5.6 assigns to-do item to newLi in the HTML
      newLi.innerHTML = toDo.title;

      //5.7 appends newLi to the to-do list
      toDoList.appendChild(newLi);

      //5.8 appends a checkbox to each newLi
      newLi.appendChild(checkbox);

      //6.1 append the remove button to each newLi
      newLi.appendChild(removeToDo);
    });
  }

  //3.1) Event Listener - catches 'submit', prevents page reload,
  // and invokes the function createNewToDo
  addToDoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    createNewToDo();
  });

  //7) SEVENTH STEP: assign remove button event and invoke removeToDoItem()
  removeToDo.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    removeToDoItem();
  });

  //4) FOURTH STEP: add the call that controls UI based on state
  renderTheUI(toDos);
}
//1) FIRST STEP: invokes the function onReady() when page loads
window.onload = function() {
  onReady()
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>To-Do App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-Do App</h1>

    <form id="addToDoForm">
      <label for="newToDoText">New To-Do:</label>
      <input type="text" id="newToDoText">
      <button type="submit">Add To-Do!</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="toDoList">
    </ul>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe first try fixing this error you have: "Uncaught ReferenceError: removeToDo is not defined"

Comment: Open your browser console to check for errors, as you see in the snippet above it shows an error.

Comment: one hint:  you are declaring variable removeToDo inside a renderTheUI function, but adding a listener to it outside that function (e.g. STEP 7) - where that variable doesn't exist.

Comment: again your removeToDoItem doesn't make sense, inside you have:     newLi.toDoList.removeChild(newLi) -- but newLi has been declared elsewhere. maybe you wanna add STEP 7 inside foreach from STEP 5

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! I've only been learning JS for four weeks, and sometimes it has me hitting my head against the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding click event listener to removeToDo whereas removeToDo is is present only inside renderUI function. So your seventh step is wrong.
you need to add Event listener inside createUI itself. Replace your script with below code

```
//2) SECOND STEP: build the function that will control everything
function onReady() {

  //2.1) creates and houses the current state of to-do list
  var toDos = [];

  //3) THIRD STEP: Event Listener - this accesses the HTML form element
  var addToDoForm = document.getElementById('addToDoForm');

  //2.2) build function that creates/adds list items
  function createNewToDo() {

    //2.3) accesses the text input from the form
    var newToDoText = document.getElementById('newToDoText');

    //2.4) adds new item to the toDos array
    toDos.push({
      title: newToDoText.value,
      complete: false
    });

    //2.5) clears the text in the form input field so user doesn't need to
    newToDoText.value='';

    renderTheUI(toDos);
  }

  //8) EIGHT STEP: build function that deletes list item
  function removeToDoItem(index) {
    console.log(toDos);
    toDos.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(toDos);
    renderTheUI(toDos);
  }

  //5) FIFTH STEP: build the function that will render the UI
  function renderTheUI(toDos) {

    //5.1) Accesses the <ul> in the HTML
    var toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoList');

    //5.9 sets each newLi to an empty string
    toDoList.innerHTML = '';

    //5.2) Use forEach() array method to render each to-do as an <li> in the <ul>
    toDos.forEach(function(toDo, index) {
            //5.3 creates new <li>
      var newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.setAttribute('id', 'myLi');

      //5.4 creates new checkbox
      var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

      //6) SIXTH STEP: create remove button and set its attributes
      var removeToDo = document.createElement('input');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('value', 'remove');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('id', 'removeButton');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('class', 'removeButton');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('data-index', index);

      //5.5 set var checkbox as a type checkbox
      checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

      //5.6 assigns to-do item to newLi in the HTML
      newLi.innerHTML = toDo.title;

      //5.7 appends newLi to the to-do list
      toDoList.appendChild(newLi);

      //5.8 appends a checkbox to each newLi
      newLi.appendChild(checkbox);

      //6.1 append the remove button to each newLi
      newLi.appendChild(removeToDo);

      removeToDo.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        removeToDoItem(index);
      });
    });
  }

  //3.1) Event Listener - catches 'submit', prevents page reload,
  // and invokes the function createNewToDo
  addToDoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    createNewToDo();
  });

  //4) FOURTH STEP: add the call that controls UI based on state
  renderTheUI(toDos);
}
onReady();
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code, i have explained them below using comments.
I have removed your comments so you can find mine easily

```
function onReady() {
  var toDos = [];

  var addToDoForm = document.getElementById('addToDoForm');

  function createNewToDo() {

    var newToDoText = document.getElementById('newToDoText');

    toDos.push({
      title: newToDoText.value,
      complete: false
    });

    newToDoText.value='';
    renderTheUI(toDos);
  }

  function removeToDoItem() {
    // the parameters used here should be defined in any of the parent scopes of this function declaration
    // Example: Following variables are accessible inside this function
    // [toDos, renderTheUI] (created in parent scope of this function "onReady")
    // [onReady] (created in parent scope of onReady "window")
    // but newLi is not defined in any of the parent scopes. So, you should pass newLi as parameter to this function

    // newLi passed as parameter will not have a property toDoList
    newLi.toDoList.removeChild(newLi);
    renderTheUI(toDos);
  }

  function renderTheUI(toDos) {
    var toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoList');

    toDoList.innerHTML = '';

    toDos.forEach(function(toDo) {

      var newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.setAttribute('id', 'myLi');

      var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

      var removeToDo = document.createElement('input');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('value', 'remove');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('id', 'removeButton');

      checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

      newLi.innerHTML = toDo.title;

      toDoList.appendChild(newLi);

      newLi.appendChild(checkbox);

      newLi.appendChild(removeToDo);
    });
  }


  addToDoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    createNewToDo();
  });

  // Same as above, removeToDo is not accessible here as is it not defined in the parent scope
  removeToDo.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Here you can access the element the click event is triggered on from "this"
    // You want to remove the "li" element that contains this button
    // You can get it from "this.parentElement", you can pass it to removeToDoItem
    removeToDoItem();
  });

  renderTheUI(toDos);
}
window.onload = function() {
  onReady()
};
```

I have made the changes to your code and fixed the issues i have mentioned above

**Solution:**

```js
//2) SECOND STEP: build the function that will control everything
function onReady() {

  //2.1) creates and houses the current state of to-do list
  var toDos = [];

  //3) THIRD STEP: Event Listener - this accesses the HTML form element
  var addToDoForm = document.getElementById('addToDoForm');

  //2.2) build function that creates/adds list items
  function createNewToDo() {

    //2.3) accesses the text input from the form
    var newToDoText = document.getElementById('newToDoText');

    //2.4) adds new item to the toDos array
    toDos.push({
      title: newToDoText.value,
      complete: false
    });

    //2.5) clears the text in the form input field so user doesn't need to
    newToDoText.value='';

    renderTheUI(toDos);
  }

  //8) EIGHT STEP: build function that deletes list item
  function removeToDoItem(newLi) {
    var toDoList = newLi.parentElement;

    // renderTheUI will render the same li again as it is still in the toDos array, you will have to remove the array entry
    // Get the index of the newLi inside it's parent
    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(toDoList.children, newLi);
    // Remove the entry in toDos at that index, we are using same index as li's are the only elements inside toDos
    toDos.splice(index, 1);
    // Remove the li element now
    toDoList.removeChild(newLi);

    // No need to call the renderTheUI here as the li is already removed and the result would be same
    // renderTheUI(toDos);
  }

  //5) FIFTH STEP: build the function that will render the UI
  function renderTheUI(toDos) {

    //5.1) Accesses the <ul> in the HTML
    var toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoList');

    //5.9 sets each newLi to an empty string
    toDoList.innerHTML = '';

    //5.2) Use forEach() array method to render each to-do as an <li> in the <ul>
    toDos.forEach(function(toDo) {

      //5.3 creates new <li>
      var newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.setAttribute('id', 'myLi');

      //5.4 creates new checkbox
      var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

      //6) SIXTH STEP: create remove button and set its attributes
      var removeToDo = document.createElement('input');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('value', 'remove');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('id', 'removeButton');

      //7) SEVENTH STEP: assign remove button event and invoke removeToDoItem()
      removeToDo.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // You can access newLi here as it is decalred in the parent scope
        removeToDoItem(newLi);
      });

      //5.5 set var checkbox as a type checkbox
      checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

      //5.6 assigns to-do item to newLi in the HTML
      newLi.innerHTML = toDo.title;

      //5.7 appends newLi to the to-do list
      toDoList.appendChild(newLi);

      //5.8 appends a checkbox to each newLi
      newLi.appendChild(checkbox);

      //6.1 append the remove button to each newLi
      newLi.appendChild(removeToDo);
    });
  }

  //3.1) Event Listener - catches 'submit', prevents page reload,
  // and invokes the function createNewToDo
  addToDoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    createNewToDo();
  });

  //4) FOURTH STEP: add the call that controls UI based on state
  renderTheUI(toDos);
}
//1) FIRST STEP: invokes the function onReady() when page loads
window.onload = function() {
  onReady()
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>To-Do App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-Do App</h1>

    <form id="addToDoForm">
      <label for="newToDoText">New To-Do:</label>
      <input type="text" id="newToDoText">
      <button type="submit">Add To-Do!</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="toDoList">
    </ul>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT-- A better solution in terms of performance**

```
//2) SECOND STEP: build the function that will control everything
function onReady() {

  //2.1) creates and houses the current state of to-do list
  var toDos = [];

  //3) THIRD STEP: Event Listener - this accesses the HTML form element
  var addToDoForm = document.getElementById('addToDoForm');

  //2.2) build function that creates/adds list items
  function createNewToDo() {

    //2.3) accesses the text input from the form
    var newToDoText = document.getElementById('newToDoText');

    //2.4) adds new item to the toDos array
    toDos.push({
      title: newToDoText.value,
      complete: false
    });

    //2.5) clears the text in the form input field so user doesn't need to
    newToDoText.value='';

    renderTheUI(toDos);
  }

  //5) FIFTH STEP: build the function that will render the UI
  function renderTheUI(toDos) {

    //5.1) Accesses the <ul> in the HTML
    var toDoList = document.getElementById('toDoList');

    //5.9 sets each newLi to an empty string
    toDoList.innerHTML = '';

    //5.2) Use forEach() array method to render each to-do as an <li> in the <ul>
    toDos.forEach(function(toDo, index) {

      //5.3 creates new <li>
      var newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.setAttribute('id', 'myLi');

      //5.4 creates new checkbox
      var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

      //6) SIXTH STEP: create remove button and set its attributes
      var removeToDo = document.createElement('input');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('type', 'button');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('value', 'remove');
      removeToDo.setAttribute('id', 'removeButton');

      //7) SEVENTH STEP: assign remove button event and invoke removeToDoItem()
      removeToDo.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Remove the entry in toDos at the index
        toDos.splice(index, 1);
        // Remove the li element
        toDoList.removeChild(newLi);
      });

      //5.5 set var checkbox as a type checkbox
      checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

      //5.6 assigns to-do item to newLi in the HTML
      newLi.innerHTML = toDo.title;

      //5.7 appends newLi to the to-do list
      toDoList.appendChild(newLi);

      //5.8 appends a checkbox to each newLi
      newLi.appendChild(checkbox);

      //6.1 append the remove button to each newLi
      newLi.appendChild(removeToDo);
    });
  }

  //3.1) Event Listener - catches 'submit', prevents page reload,
  // and invokes the function createNewToDo
  addToDoForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    createNewToDo();
  });

  //4) FOURTH STEP: add the call that controls UI based on state
  renderTheUI(toDos);
}
//1) FIRST STEP: invokes the function onReady() when page loads
window.onload = function() {
  onReady()
};
```

Comment: Getting index as @tapas mentioned will be better than what i did

Comment: Thanks for the thorough feedback, @Avcs. Your explanation was very understandable.